# Using Python to extract tweets - how to save a limited amount of variables

Tags: python, twitter, tweets

I am new to python trying to extract tweets for a research project.

I use the library searchtweets. Now I want to print only a few variables from the mass I receive from twitter.
I simply do not understand why this code writes all variables  - I only want a view variables. created_at, text, extended_tweet, user screen_name, user name..
In genereal I would really love to understand how toprint the variables I need. I am really desperate as I do not understand it.
Here are the variables that can be used: [HERE](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object#:%7E:text=Tweets%20are%20also%20known%20as,object%20to%20several%20child%20objects)

```html
#above yaml...keys... 

import json
from searchtweets import load_credentials, gen_rule_payload, ResultStream

premium_search_args = load_credentials("twitter_keys.yaml",
                                       yaml_key="search_tweets_api",
                                       env_overwrite=False)

rule = gen_rule_payload(SEARCH_QUERY,
                        results_per_call=RESULTS_PER_CALL,
                        from_date=FROM_DATE,
                        to_date=TO_DATE
                        )

rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
                  max_results=MAX_RESULTS,
                  **premium_search_args)

with open(FILENAME, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    n = 0
    for tweet in rs.stream():
        n += 1
        if n % PRINT_AFTER_X == 0:
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(str(n), tweet['created_at']))
        json.dump(tweet, f)
        f.write('\n')
        
#Use csv writer
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)


for tweet in rs.stream(): # how can I write it into an excel file? the relevant variables. # all variables in rs saved?

    # Write a row to the CSV file. I use encode UTF-8
    csvWriter.writerow([
        tweet.created_at,
        tweet.text,
        tweet.extended_tweet
        #tweet.in_reply_to_status_id,
          ])
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.extended_tweet)

#does not work
```

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied the contents of the "tweet" variable to the dictionary using json?

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Sorry, I don't really understand the question. Could you make an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a json string from the server, you need to convert it to a dictionary using the json library to be able to take the values of the dictionary keys from it

for example:

```
import json

# write the server response to the variable
tweet = '''{
 "created_at": "Wed Oct 10 20:19:24 +0000 2018",
 "id": 1050118621198921728,
 "id_str": "1050118621198921728",
 "text": "To make room for more expression, we will now count all emojis as equal—including those with gender‍‍‍ ‍‍and skin t… https://.../...",
 "user": {},
 "entities": {}
}'''

dict_tweet = json.loads(tweet) # convert the server response to dict

created_at = dict_tweet['created_at']

print(created_at) # now we can ask him for the value of any key
```

it displays: "Wed Oct 10 20:19:24 +0000 2018"

Comment: I changed the code - I did this - look above - I imported the json .- but I cannot save only selected variables. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: note, you are still writing a whole variable `json.dump(tweet, f)` to the file, instead of writing a specific key `json.dump(tweet['created_at']), f)`

Comment: Thanks again!! It gets clearer! :)
However i did this now:  
`json.dump(tweet['created_at', 'text','extended_tweet'], f)`
Now I get a keyError.
For extended_tweet it seems clear why as in the json with all variables i written, extended_tweet has a subcategory: {"created_at":"DATE", "text":text,max140char",..., "extended_tweet": {"full_text": "TEXT STRING"}, "NextVariable":,..
Howver if i only put `json.dump(tweet['created_at', 'text'], f)` it does not work, too. ANd I need the full text!
Thanks :)

Comment: It's because of you can get only one key from dictionary. 
Try `json.dump(tweet['created_at'] + ' - ' + tweet['text'], f)`

Comment: nice that worked :)
one issue remains the it's perfect :) I need the extended tweet. , which has a subcategory. 
`json.dump(tweet['created_at'] + ' - ' + tweet['text'] + tweet ["extended_tweet": ["full_text"]], f)` 
If I try it like this - the following error comes : TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

extended_tweet seems to be an extra object?
`{
 "created_at": "DATE",
 "id_str": "55",
 "text": "Just another Tweet Max 140 Chars",
 "display_text_range": [0, 140],
 "truncated": true,
 "user": {
  "id_str": "0",
 },
 "extended_tweet": {
  "full_text": ""
      }]
}`

Comment: the dictionary is here:[link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json)

Comment: `tweet["extended_tweet"]["full_text"]`, if you want to get values deeper in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :)
I still get a key error if I do it like this :( you have an idea? 
`json.dump(tweet['created_at'] + ' - ' + tweet['text'] + ' - ' + tweet["extended_tweet"]["full_text"], f)`  
--> KeyError: 'extended_tweet'

Comment: this may be because there is no "extended_tweet" key in the dictionary

Comment: It is! I thnik the issue is that not all tweets are extended tweets - so an if condition has to be in the code. I tried like this but it does not work.:((
`with open(FILENAME, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    n = 0
    for tweet in rs.stream():
        n += 1
        if n % PRINT_AFTER_X == 0:
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(str(n), tweet['created_at']))
    if 'extended_tweet' in tweet: 
        json.dumb(tweet['created_at']+ ' - '+tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text'],f)
    else:
        json.dump(tweet['created_at'] + ' - ' + tweet['text'], f)
f.write('\n')`

Comment: an idea? :) @EightShift